# Add character at given position using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, insert, char, c-strings

Running into an issue with setting character at a specific position using pointers in C.

The code is accurately placing the character in the correct position, but the current character in that position is not being moved over.

The issue is that the current letter is being skipped over when position is found, but adding `*dest++ = *string` within the IF block when position is found causes the program to halt.

**Example:**
the string is "bigmoney". Letter to add is 'X'. The position is 3.

**Output should be "bigXmoney"**

**Current output is "bigXoney"** using the code below.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Updated code:**

```
void addLetter(char string[STRING_LENGTH], char letterToAdd, int pos)
{
    // store array in pointer
    char *stringHolder = string;
    char *dest = string;
    int posCounter = 0;

    // loop through string while not null
    while (*stringHolder) {
        // position found, add the character
        if (posCounter == pos) {
            *dest++ = letterToAdd;
        } else {
            *dest++ = *stringHolder;
        }

        // increment position counter
        posCounter++;

        // move the pointer position
        stringHolder++;
    }
    //reset stringholder pointer;
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

Comment: You are reading from and writing to the same string. A bit of care needs to be taken to preserve the character you just overwrote because after, it's gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use standard C string functions then the function can look the following way

```
char * addLetter( char s[], char c, size_t pos )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < pos && s[i] ) ++i;

    if ( i == pos )
    {
        do 
        {
            char tmp = s[i];
            s[i++] = c;
            c = tmp;
        } while ( c );

        s[i] = c;
    }

    return s;
}
```

If you need to use only pointers inside the function then it can look like

```
char * addLetter( char s[], char c, size_t pos )
{
    char *p = s;

    while ( *p && p != s + pos  ) ++p;

    if ( p == s + pos )
    {
        do 
        {
            char tmp = *p;
            *p++ = c;
            c = tmp;
        } while ( c );

        *p = c;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

char * addLetter( char s[], char c, size_t pos )
{
    char *p = s;

    while ( *p && p != s + pos  ) ++p;

    if ( p == s + pos )
    {
        do 
        {
            char tmp = *p;
            *p++ = c;
            c = tmp;
        } while ( c );

        *p = c;
    }

    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t STRING_LENGTH = 10;
    char s[STRING_LENGTH] = "bigmoney"; 

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << addLetter( s, 'X', 3 ) << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
bigmoney
bigXmoney
```

Comment: @cosmoo I had a typo in the character array definition omitting the array size. Now I have updated it. That is the array shall have enough space to contain one more character.:)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way: [Use `std::string::insert`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert)

Assuming `std::string` is forbidden in this assignment, start at the end of the string and work backward until you pass `pos` moving each character (including the null terminator) up one slot. Now you have an empty spot at `pos` and can safely write in the new value.

Answer (score -1):

```
shorter if memcpy is allowed.

  char * addLetter(char s[], char c, size_t pos)
    {
        int len = strlen(s);
        if (pos > len || len + 1 >= STRING_LENGTH)
            return NULL;
        else
        {
            **memcpy(s + pos + 1, s + pos, len - pos);
            s[pos] = c;**
            return s;
        }

    }
```